# How can I submit a form and upload a file using ajax to a spring controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have a form which contains four fields, the file, the name, the type (just a string) and the taskInstanceId.

```
<form>
   <table id="documentDetailsTable">
       <tr>
           <td>Document Type: </td>
           <td><select id="documentType" name="type"> </select></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
              Document Name:
           </td>
           <td>
              <input type="text" id="documentName" name="name"/>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="newFile">
           <td>
              Choose a file:
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="file" name="file" />
           </td>
    </table>
    <input type="text" style="display: none;" name="taskInstanceId" id="taskInstanceId">

     <input id="uploadButton" value="Upload" type="submit"/>
     <input class="closeButton" id="closeNew" value="Close" type="button"/>
 </form>
```

If I submit this form it will connect to my FileUploadController and the file will upload.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formTask.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleFormTaskUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam("type") String type,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("taskInstanceId") int taskInstanceId)...//rest of the code
```

Now I would like to submit this form using jquery/json instead so that I can return a string indicating a successful upload and then display a dialog on the page indicating this. (I don't want to return a new ModelAndView).

So using the same html form I create a new Controller function...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formTask2.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormTaskUpload2(UploadTaskDocument myNewUpload)).../rest of the code
```

Now I would like to submit the form above using jQuery. My attempt is here.

This function is called everytime the file is changed.

```
function prepareUpload(event)
{
    files = event.target.files;
}
```

And this one is called when the form is submitted.

```
function uploadFiles(event)
{
event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

var data;
data = {
    documentName: $("#documentName").val(),
    documentType: $("#documentType").val(),
    taskInstanceId: selectedTaskInstanceId,
    uploadedfiles: files
};
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
    url: '/SafeSiteLive/formTask2.json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: json,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false, // Don't process the files
    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if (typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            //submitForm(event, data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
}
```

The Json data looks like this before it's posted...

[image]

But once it reaches the server everything is null...

[image]

Comment: Yes, looks alright, except for your `submitForm` in the sucess case of your  `jQuery.ajax` call. Not sure what `submitForm` does but it must not submit the form anymore since you did send the data already with the ajax request. In the sucess case you invoke what should be done if the form data was processed and you have a success response from the server.

Comment: Ignore that, I just haven't got to coding that stage yet.

The problem I'm having now is that I get a 404 error when trying to submit the ajax and I have no clue why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this might seem a bit different than your solution but I would go forth by doing the following.

As I understand you want to upload the data using ajax to your controller and avoid a post back, and then return a string and nothing but a string. I would do as follows.

You have your form:

```
<form> //Remove the method type as well as where the post should happen to ensure that you do not have to prevent default behavior
   <table id="documentDetailsTable">
       <tr>
           <td>Document Type: </td>
           <td><select id="documentType" name="type"> </select></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
              Document Name:
           </td>
           <td>
              <input type="text" id="documentName" name="name"/>
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="newFile">
           <td>
              Choose a file:
           </td>
           <td>
               <input type="file" name="file" />
           </td>
    </table>
    <input type="text" style="display: none;" name="taskInstanceId" id="taskInstanceId">

     <input id="uploadButton" value="Upload" onclick('uploadFiles()')/> //Add //the event to your submit button and remove the submit from itself
     <input class="closeButton" id="closeNew" value="Close" type="button"/>
 </form>
```

Your JQuery:

```
//Stays the same I would suggest using a object type and then stringify it as follows
function uploadFiles(event)
{
event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

// START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

// Create a formdata object and add the files
//var data = new FormData();
//.each(files, function (key, value)
//{
//    data.append(key, value);
//});
//data.append('documentName', $("#documentName").val());
//data.append('documentType', $("#documentType").val());
//data.append('taskInstanceId', $("#taskInstanceId").val());

// Create a objectobject and add the files
var data;
data = {
    documentName:$("#documentName").val(),
    documentType:$("#documentType").val(),
    taskInstanceId:$("#taskInstanceId").val(),
    uploadedfiles: files
}
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
$.ajax({
    url: '/SafeSiteLive/formTask2.do',
    type: 'POST',
    data: json,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false, // Don't process the files
    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if (typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            submitForm(event, data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
}
```

In your controller:

As you are working with MVC, please use a Model as it is the correct fashion to catch a parameter.

```
public String handleFormTaskUpload2(UploadedFile mynewUpload )
{
//rest of code here
}
```

Your Model will then look something to this.

```
public class UploadedFile
{
   public string documentName{get;set}
   public string documentType{get;set}
   public string taskInstanceId{get;set}
   prop List<byte[]> files {get;set}
}
```

Hope this helps, please let me know if you still don't understand

Comment: Thanks for this it looks like a cleaner way of doing this and it got rid of my 404 error. But for some reason the data that reaches the server is null. I've updated my main post with the new code I'm using...